# Can we restrict an email link from getting encoded in Sengrid?

Tags: sendgrid

I am doing universal linking for android and IOS apps but as the links in the email are encoded by Sendgrid. It is not working as expected. Is there a way to stop the email links from getting encoded in Sendgrid configuration

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sendgrid encodes the links to allow for clicktracking. Turn off clicktracking to stop the encoding of the URLs.